# Docker link containers

Tags: docker, nginx

I need to setup nginx-proxy container to forward requests to the container with my app. I use the following commands to start containers:

```
# app
docker run -d -p 8080:2368 \
  --name app \
  app

# nginx
docker run -d -p 80:8080 \
  --name nginx-proxy \
  jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

But when I try to access port 80 on my server, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. It's clear for me that nginx container is forwarding not the port I want because on server port 8080 I can access the app.
I tried using `network` like this:

```
# network
docker network create -d bridge net

# app
docker run -d -p 8080:2368 \
  --name app \
  --network net \
  app

# nginx
docker run -d -p 80:8080 \
  --name nginx-proxy \
  --network net \
  jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

But the result seems to be the same.
I need to understand how to make nginx container proxy requests from server port 80 to my app.

Comment: your nginx proxy might be running on 80 inside container? if you can share you nginx proxy conf?

Comment: @kakabali, I use [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) container with defaults, haven't added any config for it. Do I need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VIRTUAL_HOST` env var with domain name for app container was required to let nginx proxy requests to the app container. No network setup or ports forwarding is needed with this approach. Here is the working setup I came up with:

```
# app
docker run -d \
  --name app \
  -e VIRTUAL_HOST=mydomain.com \
  app

# nginx
docker run -d -p 80:80 \
  --name nginx-proxy \
  jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

It is looking that your app is running on port 2368 which users should not need to reach directly. So the `app` container's port does not need to be exposed.

You are correct in creating a bridge network and create the containers on it.

You need to remove port mapping from `app` container and change the port mapping of `nginx-proxy` container from `80:8080` to `80:80`.

You also need to setup `nginx-proxy` to proxy requests from port 80 to `app:2386`

This way users hitting the port 80 on the host machine Docker runs will be proxied to your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it, but still getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, my new setup looks like this: pastebin.com/FH3NYSWt, did I miss some of the edits you proposed?

Comment: I edited my answer. I am not familiar with `jwilder/nginx-proxy` but in normal nginx proxy setup, you should configure nginx to forward requests to `app:2386`. Please refer to the example setup https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Thanks, found out that `jwilder/nginx-proxy` needed `VIRTUAL_HOST` to be set for the app container in order to proxy to it, added answer with this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991294/8529483